# How to link post to user?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a foreign key to User in my Post model, which is meant to give each post an Author attribute. I have tested this using two dummy accounts. For example, when account B writes a post, his name will be displayed in the author field. This works fine when B is logged in. However, when I logout B and login A, the article which was written by B is now attributed to A. How do I fix this, so that the author field is actually dependent on the author of the post, and not whichever user is currently logged in?

Post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    summary = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    content = RichTextField()
    draft = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    upvote = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    vote = Vote
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(
        'category.Category',
        help_text='Categorize this item.'
    )
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(
        'category.Tag',
        help_text='Tag this item.'
    )
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('posts:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

In the template:

```
<p><h5><B><a href="#"><span class="link">{{ post.user.first_name }} {{ post.user.last_name }}</span></a></B></h5></p>
```

Comment: You'll need to show some code. Are you actually using the post's user attribute, rather than request.user?

Comment: I'm using user = models.ForeignKey(User)

Comment: I mean in the part where you display the post author.

Comment: Oh, in the view? I use {{post.user.full_name}} Should it be request.post.get.user?

Comment: No, what you have is fine. Where exactly are you seeing the logged-in user then?